# Find similar (or equal consecutive items in a list)

Tags: c#, list

I'm working on software that lets instructors grade papers, and I need to find out if an instructor has given the same grade to 3 consecutive papers. Essentially I have a list of grades:

80,81,90,90,90,100,85,86,86,79,95,95,95

I'd need to identify the 90's and the 95's in this list (they each are consecutively given 3 times).

PS - for the guy who keeps flagging my posts as "homework," just because I'm dealing students and grades doesn't mean it's a classroom assignment. Jiminy.

Answer (score 7):

You can do this quite easily with looping through over `i` from 2 to `list.Length` and check if `list[i] == list[i - 1] && list[i - 1] == list[i - 2]`.

For instance, it can be written like this:

```
var list = new[] { 80,81,90,90,90,100,85,86,86,79,95,95,95 };
var dupes = new List<int>();
for(var i = 2; i < list.Length; i++) {
    if(list[i] == list[i - 1] && list[i] == list[i - 2])
        dupes.Add(list[i]);
}
```

**[Edit]**
Here's a running example: http://ideone.com/UGwFwq

If you would not like double reported when there are 4 (or more) equals in a row, a good way to prevent that from happening is simply keeping a temp variable on the previous "3 in a row" was found and check against that before you append to the dupes list.

Something like this:

```
var list = new[] { 80,81,90,90,90,90,90,90,100,85,86,86,79,95,95,95,95 };
var dupes = new List<int>();
int? prev = null;
for(var i = 2; i < list.Length; i++) {
    if(list[i] == list[i - 1] && list[i] == list[i - 2]) {
        if(!prev.HasValue || prev.Value != list[i]) {
            dupes.Add(list[i]);
            prev = list[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Showcase: http://ideone.com/jbokMQ

**[Edit 2]**
And if for some reason you **need** to run this in a LINQ-like manner (for instance if you have a HUGE dataset or a stream of data and you want to run this in a lazy manner), a solution to that can be found here: http://ideone.com/R1ZBVk

Comment: I so would have liked a linq way of doing this, but the plain old for loop works well here. :)

Comment: Good basic idea, but it will give multiple reports on eg `,90,90,90,90,` or `,90,90,90,95,90,90,90,`; the original question is not clear on what should be done in this case.

Comment: @AdrianHHH I fixed that :)

Comment: @DavidArno I added a Lazy State-machine generating method of doing it as well. It doesn't use any of the LINQ methods, but I don't really see the point in that for this task.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a general purpose method that groups consecutive items whose selected values are equal:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TSource>> GroupConsecutive<TSource, TKey>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> selector)
{
    using (var iterator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!iterator.MoveNext())
            yield break;

        TKey lastKey = selector(iterator.Current);
        List<TSource> list = new List<TSource>() { iterator.Current };
        IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer = EqualityComparer<TKey>.Default;

        while (iterator.MoveNext())
        {
            TKey nextKey = selector(iterator.Current);
            if (comparer.Equals(lastKey, nextKey))
            {
                list.Add(iterator.Current);
            }
            else
            {
                yield return list;
                lastKey = nextKey;
                list = new List<TSource>() { iterator.Current };
            }
        }

        yield return list;
    }
}
```

We can now use this on your data like so:

```
var duplicates = data.GroupConsecutive(n => n)
    .Where(group => group.Count() >= 3);
    .Select(group => group.First());
```

Comment: Nice. I like it. I will save this for later :). Though, I probably would have returned a new data-type with something like `{ Count = count, Value = value }` given that you return the same value a lot of times. Though, it might not always be the case given that even though something is "Equal", might not mean they are the same...

Comment: @Alxandr In this case I just returned the duplicated items (one of each).  If you want to include the counts, that's entirely doable, or even the entire list of values (which would generally be worth doing if you selected something other than "itself" as the selector).

Comment: Ah, yes, I meant on the `GroupConsecutive`-method itself, not on the statement you added at the end. Though, with regards to selecting something other than "itself", I wholeheartedly agree. It's better to return all the items :).

Comment: @Alxandr Ah, in that case you'd want it to be for a version that doesn't accept a selector; if you have a selector you probably don't want just one item, you'd want them all.  If you're grouping on the item itself you most likely just need one of them.  Doing that wouldn't be a terribly involved alteration of the method; mostly just removing the selector stuff and changing the list to a single item.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and Dirty:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication3 {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            List<byte> A = new List<byte>{80,81,90,90,90,100,85,86,86,79,95,95,95};
            byte last = 0;
            int count = 0;
            foreach (byte b in A) {

                if (b == last) count++;
                else count = 0;
                if (count >=2) Console.WriteLine("Instructor has given " + b + " " +     (count+1) + " times in a row");
                last = b;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
int intDuplicateCriteria = 2; //Any grade duplicated by a value greater than 2 
int[] lstGrades = new[] { 80, 81, 90, 90, 90, 100, 85, 86, 86, 79, 95, 95, 95 };

var lstDuplicate = lstGrades
                 .GroupBy(grade => grade)
                 .Where(g => g.Count() > intDuplicateCriteria)
                 .Select(g => g.Key);


//Display consecutively grades given 3 times
foreach (var d in lstDuplicate)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(d.ToString());               
    }
```